# why does my app crash when my masterview controller tries to launch my detail view?

Tags: ios

I am trying to make my first iOS app after doing a few tutorials. I am making  a simple headline/news reader that pulls New Orleans Saints headlines and stories as json from an ESPN API, displays the headlines in a table view, and then displays the text of the story in a detail view when the user taps a headline.

The app compiles and runs without errors or warnings. The prepareForSegue method executes when the user taps a headline in the  top tableview. I can step thru this code in the debugger. If I step thru the prepareForSegue method, it calls the detailViewController's setStory method, which in turn calls the configureview method. But then it takes me to main.m and the app closes, without showing the detail view.

I am a noob. What am I missing? Why don't I see the detail view? Maybe I need an IBAction to load the IBOutlet?

saintsMasterViewController.m

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"showDetail"]) {
        saintsDetailViewController *detailViewController = [segue destinationViewController];
        saintsNewsStory* displayThisStory =[self.dataController objectInListAtIndex:[self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow].row];
        [detailViewController setStory:displayThisStory];
    }
}
```

saintsDetailViewController.m

```
- (void)setStory:(saintsNewsStory *)newStory
{
 //   if (_story != newStory) {
        _story = newStory;
        // Update the view.
     //   [self configureView];
  //  }
}


- (void)configureView
{
    self.storyText.text = self.story.storyText;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad     //the app never gets here. if i put a breakpoint here it never gets here
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    [self configureView];
}
```

saintsDetailViewController.h

```
@class saintsNewsStory;
@interface saintsDetailViewController : UIViewController
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextView *storyText;
@property (retain, nonatomic) saintsNewsStory *story;
@end
```

The console shows this error:

SaintsHeadlineReader[9608:11303] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[ setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key detailDescriptionLabel.'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x1c90012 0x10cde7e 0x1d18fb1 0xb7a711 0xafbec8 0xafb9b7 0xb26428 0x2320cc 0x10e1663 0x1c8b45a 0x230bcf 0xf5e37 0xf6418 0xf6648 0xf6882 0x102235 0x3013d2 0xff4f3 0xff777 0xff7b7 0x46afe2 0x45cad9 0x45cb54 0xc4899 0xc4b3d 0xacbe83 0x1c4f376 0x1c4ee06 0x1c36a82 0x1c35f44 0x1c35e1b 0x1bea7e3 0x1bea668 0x1565c 0x204d 0x1f75 0x1)
libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception

It seems like textview has a detail label and maybe I needed an outlet for that?

Comment: Could you try to comment the code in `prepareForSegue` and see if your detail ViewController loads?

Answer (score 0):

Change this line :

```
saintsDetailViewController *detailViewController = [segue destinationViewController];
```

To this:

```
saintsDetailViewController *detailViewController = (saintsDetailViewController *)[segue destinationViewController];
```

---

EDIT:
You should show your view first and then call the `configureView` method. Try to call `configureView` in `viewDidLoad` of that ViewController.

```
- (void)setStory:(saintsNewsStory *)newStory
{
 //   if (_story != newStory) {
        _story = newStory;
        // Update the view.
       // [self configureView];
  //  }
}


-(void) viewDidLoad {
      [self configureView];
}


- (void)configureView
{
    self.storyText.text = self.story.storyText; //the app gets to here but does not show the view. why?
}
```

Comment: did not work, unfortunately. here is the method, as you suggest.- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"showDetail"]) {
        saintsDetailViewController *detailViewController = (saintsDetailViewController *)[segue destinationViewController];
        saintsNewsStory* displayThisStory =[self.dataController objectInListAtIndex:[self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow].row];
        [detailViewController setStory:displayThisStory];
    }
}

Comment: thanks again for your help. i made the suggested to calling configure view but it still does not load

Comment: view did load is never called. if i put a breakpoint to viewdid load it never gets there

Answer (score 0):

Test my theory.  Put `NSLog(@"%d", [self.yourTableView indexPathForSelectedRow].row);` in your current `prepareForSegue` method immediately before or after the line you currently use the `indexPathForSelectedRow`, and see what it is returning in your console. Probably 0.

Instead of connecting the segue from the UITableViewCell Prototype to the DetailViewController, connect it from the UITableViewController to the DetailViewController and then use the methods below:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    SaintsDetailViewController *detailViewController = [[SaintsDetailViewController alloc] init];
    saintsNewsStory* displayThisStory =[self.dataController objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [detailViewController setStory:displayThisStory];
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"showDetail" sender:indexPath];
}
```

and your `prepareForSegue:` method:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"showDetail"]) {
        saintsDetailViewController *detailViewController = [segue destinationViewController];
    }
}
```

Comment: the console prints 1, for the line you suggest